# How to configure Openstack on multiple physical servers?

Tags: installation, openstack

From the book "OpenStack Cloud Computing Cookbook", I find that all the installation of the openstack is on VMs. I am wondering is it possible to install the openstack directly on physical servers without VMs?

Actually, by installing openstack on VMs, the situation is that when I install the compute node (Nova) on the VM of server 1, I cannot use it to manage the resources on server 2.

Is there any way I can use openstack to manage a large quantity of physical servers instead of VMs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. OpenStack was *designed* for this. The purpose of installing it to VMs is primarily for evaluation, testing and learning, rather than production deployment.